# Change default locale of iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsnumberformatter

I am creating an app in Swedish and it should only run in Swedish no matter what the device locale is. I am wondering how I set the default locale for my app to be swedish i.e. `sv_SE`. When I create a `NSNumberFormatter` I want it to localize to `sv_SE` by default

In the project info settings "Localization" only contains Swedish.

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Locale: %@", nf.locale.localeIdentifier);

//Returns Locale: en_US
```

Am I missing such an overall setting or do I have to manually localize all my objects to Swedish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing automatic inside iOS app runtime that can make it run in your desired locale. Yes, you need to localize every resource, text and messages that you want to display to sv_SE.

You can make your app aware about when the user alters a locale (e.g. by going inside iphone settings), by listening to ***NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification*** notification.

Once done, if you want additional languages too, you can use `NSLocalizedString` function to invoke your desired locale every time you need to display a translation. This will show translated value based on user's set locale under Language Settings.

[NSLocale documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001224-47482) gives further insights.

Answer (score 0):

As formatters can be an expensive resource it's often a good idea to cache their creation. If you are going to do this you could easily make a simple category that gives you the formatter configured the way you need it and cached - for example if I needed currencies formatted in a particular way I would consider the following

```
- (NSNumberFormatter *)tla_currencyFormatter;
{
  static NSString *TLACurrencyFormatterKey = @"TLACurrencyFormatterKey";

  NSMutableDictionary *threadDictionary = [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary];

  NSNumberFormatter *formatter = threadDictionary[TLACurrencyFormatterKey];

  if (!formatter) {
    formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    // configure formatter
    threadDictionary[TLACurrencyFormatterKey] = formatter;
  }

  return formatter;
}
```